# How To ResetPassword in Atlas MongoDB for Kotlin Android App

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native, kotlin, mongodb-atlas

I'm facing problems using MongoDB JavaScript Functions
For Example, i'm trying to Edit Authentication Password in my App,

```
const Realm = require("realm");
const appConfig = {
    id: "App_ID",
    timeout: 1000,
    app: {
        name: "App_Name",
        version: "1"
    }
};
let app = new Realm.App(appConfig);
let client = app.auth.emailPassword;
await client.resetPassword(token, tokenId, newPassword);
```

1. Is The code Above Required ! i've read few docs & no where to be found !!

```
exports = (
{ token, tokenId, username, password, currentPasswordValid },
sendEmail,
securityQuestionAnswer
) => {
    // process the reset token, tokenId, username and password
    if (sendEmail) {
        context.functions.execute(
            "sendResetPasswordEmail",
            username,
            token,
            tokenId
        );
        // will wait for SDK resetPassword to be called with the token and tokenId
        return { status: "pending" };
    } else if (
        context.functions.execute(
            "validateSecurityQuestionAnswer",
            username,
            securityQuestionAnswer || currentPasswordValid
        )
    ) {
        // will set the users password to the password parameter
        return { status: "success" };
    }
```

1. How should i even send parametres to use from android studio & to what functions !!

`exports = ({ token, tokenId, username, password, currentPasswordValid },`

2. how to generate the Token & TokenId inside my APP without Sending it to Email ?  i'm only trying to update Password not reset it after forgetting it !!
3. Should i even use those JAVASCRIPT functions ? can't i Just replace them with Kotlin functions ? and how to change credentials if so !
4. Is there good ressources how to master those functions (MongoDB Docs for those functions feels Useless Sadly)